# Euribor + margin

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, finance, bond, bond-yields

I have this bond assigment where I have to calculate the CF each quarter, given a constant EURIBOR3M rate of -0,539%. There is also a 1,6% margin per annum that I have to take into account. The repayment is going to happen 4 times each year. My question is: What is the quarterly yield/rate and the yearly yield/rate?. Do I have to consider EURIBOR 3M as an annualized rate?

Comment: Not sure what the convention for your margin is but EURIBOR3M is an annualized, quarterly paid, interest rate on an Act/360 basis. The amount paid will be Principal * ((EURIBOR3M * (Actual Days in Period)/ 360)).

Comment: It gives more sense now AlRacoon. I was dividing the rates based on months, but I see that the day counter in Excel provides a more correct picture. Thank you for your time :)